# GAE Python pass variable to google map Lon/Lat

Tags: javascript, python, google-maps, google-app-engine

I want to pass the variable I get from python to Google Maps Lon/Lat

I want to know how to pass the variable into Google Maps Api longitude & latitude

or any other suggestion for making this works?

Below is my current code.

```
import webapp2

class MainHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.response.write("""
<html>
  <body>
    <form action="/2" method="post">
        longitute : <input type="text" name="longitute">
        latitute : <input type="text" name="latitute">
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
  </body>
</html>
""")

class SecondHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):


    def post(self):
        longitute = self.request.get('longitute')
        latitute = self.request.get('latitute')
        self.response.write("""
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
       #map {
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
       }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h3>My Google Maps Demo</h3>
    <div id="map"></div>
    <script>
      function initMap() {
        var uluru = {lat: {{ longitute }}, lng: {{ latitute }}};
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          zoom: 15,
          center: uluru
        });
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          position: uluru,
          map: map
        });
      }
    </script>
    <script async defer
    src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCtviKn_I3qxjLtjl6IsGPFw9zy8iU2b8Q&callback=initMap">
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
""")
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no good reason to be writing HTML code inside your Python scripts. GAE supports Jinja2 templates; as well as making your code much easier to read and write, these will also support passing variables and rendering the result.

Comment: Ok, I put the html script into another html file now, but how to pass the variable from python script to html javascript (google map api) ?

Comment: Just like any other variable in Jinja2.